# XmlNode SelectNodes returns only first occurrence when querying for text nodes

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Seeing strange behavior when querying for text nodes with the `text()` XPath function.

I have a simple XML like

```xml
<label>Matrise <foo/><foo/>GM:1<foo/></label>
```

Using `labelNode.SelectNodes("text()")` query will return the 2 expected text nodes - "Matrise" and "GM:1"

However, if I remove the `foo` nodes then there will still be two text nodes, but the query no longer returns both of them - only the first.

Why is it returning only one text node in the first case if there are clearly two text nodes?

Code example:

```cs
using System.Xml;

var xml = "<label>Matrise <foo/><foo/>GM:1<foo/></label>";
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
var labelNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("label");

Console.WriteLine("Before modifications:");
PrintTextNodesInOriginal(labelNode);

Console.WriteLine("\r\nAfter modifications:");
PrintTextNodesInModified(labelNode);


void PrintTextNodesInOriginal(XmlNode labelNode)
{
    PrintTextNodes(labelNode);
}

void PrintTextNodesInModified(XmlNode labelNode)
{
    // Remove foo nodes
    var foos = labelNode
        .SelectNodes("foo")
        .Cast<XmlNode>()
        .ToList();

    foreach (var foo in foos)
    {
        foo.ParentNode.RemoveChild(foo);
    }

    PrintTextNodes(labelNode);
}

List<XmlNode> GetTextNodes(XmlNode labelNode)
{
    return labelNode.SelectNodes("text()")
        .Cast<XmlNode>()
        .ToList();
}

void PrintTextNodes(XmlNode labelNode)
{
    var textNodes = GetTextNodes(labelNode);
    var textNodesActual = labelNode.ChildNodes
        .Cast<XmlNode>()
        .Where(node => node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
        .ToList();

    Console.WriteLine($"Nodes count using query: {textNodes.Count}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Nodes count actual: {textNodesActual.Count}");
    Console.WriteLine("Nodes' contents:");

    foreach (var textNode in textNodes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(textNode.InnerText);
    }
}
```

Expected results:

```
Before modifications:
Nodes count using query: 2
Nodes count actual: 2
Nodes' contents:
Matrise
GM:1

After modifications:
Nodes count using query: 2
Nodes count actual: 2
Nodes' contents:
Matrise
GM:1
```

Actual results:

```
Before modifications:
Nodes count using query: 2
Nodes count actual: 2
Nodes' contents:
Matrise
GM:1

After modifications:
Nodes count using query: 1
Nodes count actual: 2
Nodes' contents:
Matrise
```

Comment: It would be much better if you'd write a [mcve] which printed the results to the console, rather than showing images of a debugger. Aside from anything else, if anyone else wants to reproduce your results, they have to go to *much* more work than the "copy/paste/compile/run" experience they'd have with a minimal complete example.

Comment: @JonSkeet Added code example.

Comment: Looking into it now - although I think it would be better to remove the screenshots and debugger aspects entirely, and make sure your code separates out the "before" and "after". I'd also personally recommend avoiding XmlDocument and using LINQ to XML instead, wherever you possibly can. But it's still odd what's happening here...

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks. Removed the screenshots and updated the code example, but I might have made it actually more complicated to read, not sure.

Comment: It looks like this is "just" a bug in the XmlDocument XPath implementation. You can get text nodes by using `labelNode.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlText>()` as a workaround, but that may not fit in with what you're doing.

Comment: I see. Was planning to use this exact workaround, but was just curious why the query approach was working like that. And LINQ to XML is great, but change to that is not doable right now. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath data model does not allow the children of an element node to contain two adjacent text nodes. So while an underlying tree model such as DOM might allow this, a correct XPath implementation will treat them as if they were merged into a single node. Some XPath implementations handle this incorrectly, but it looks as if this one gets it right.

The reason for the rule in XPath is that it tries to ensure that if two XDM trees have the same XML serialization, then they are equivalent in terms of any XPath query.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! But if I understand you correctly then it is not correctly implemented here, because the text nodes don't get merged.

Comment: Yes, indeed, your output seems to suggest that.